# What data structures can be passed to Python functions as packed arguments?

Tags: python, arrays, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

In Python, one can use starred expressions to unpack variables:

```py
def unpack(*args):
    return args
```

I know that `*args` here can be a tuple, e.g. `args = (arg1, arg2, arg3)`. Besides dictionaries for `**kwargs`, what other data structures are supported for `*arg`? What happens "behind the curtain", e.g. if I do:

```py
args = numpy.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
unpack(args)
```

Comment: `asarray()` is a function, you are trying to index it. And what is `unpack`? You did not even check if your code runs!

Comment: And to answer your question: `args` is a tuple containing whatever was passed to the function as positional arguments.

Comment: The argument for `*` has to be an `Iterable` and for `**` a `Mapping`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html for a few details on this abstract base classes.

Answer (score 1):

The use cases you mentioned for python built-in data structures are the valid: lists, sets (and all that is of [Iteratable types](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable)) for `*args` (and even `range`), and dictionaries for `**kwargs` (and all that is of [Mapping Types](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping)).

NumPy array is iterable too so:

```
import numpy as np

def unpack(*args):
    x, y, z = args
    # [1 2 3]
    print(x)


xargs = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
unpack(*xargs)
```

Read more at:

- [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)
- [PEP 448 -- Additional Unpacking Generalizations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)
- [Asterisks in Python: what they are and how to use them](https://treyhunner.com/2018/10/asterisks-in-python-what-they-are-and-how-to-use-them/#Asterisks_for_unpacking_into_function_call)